# Jenkins build Error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am trying to build my first maven project in Jenkin after setup but unable to do that due to the following:

Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project FreeCRMTest: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: add Java to your PATH and remove the <executable> as a starter.

Comment: Better is to define JAVA_HOME and yes remove the executable. Furthermore check the warnings in your build cause there are some...and this means there is something wrong..

Comment: 1) Removed <executable> tag                       2)Java_Home is defined

Comment: Added screenshot of Env. variable

Comment: Restarted your IDE and/or your console..

Comment: Thanks but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Jenkins->Global Tool configuration -> "Add JDK" and give your jdk path.
Problem solved!

Hopefully its gonna help someone

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem where maven compiler plugin v3.8.1 was failing in jenkins pipeline.

*What fixed my issue?*

In "**Build Environment**" menu,

Adding `JAVA_HOME=<jdk path>` under "**Inject environment variables to the build process**" fixes the issue

[image]

Comment: It'd help a lot if you would actually say which menu this is in.